# Bash string comparison at if statement

Tags: bash

I'm becoming freaking crazy because of bash programming

I have the following:

```
result="ERROR|0"  # From a complex sed execution
IFS='|' read -a array <<< "$result"

if [ "${array[0]}" == "ERROR" ]; then
    echo "Error"
fi
```

It should print *Error*, but it doesn't.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Editing**: Actually, now it works, so I add the previous code where I get the "result" string

```
result=$( [some code that gives me an output] \
          | grep "Executed" \
          | sed s/'\(.*\) Executed \(.*\) of \(.*\) \(.*\) (.*)'/'\4|\3'/ \
        )
```

it should return a string, shouldn't it? The string I wrote before

Comment: it does for me (now that you have corrected the errors in the script)

Comment: are you sure you are running the snippet with `bash`? do you get errors? what does `echo ${array[@]}` print?

Comment: The problem is that there are not visible characters for colouring the output and it's pretty weird get a regexp for it

Comment: you are probably aware that nobody can know about extra characters if you don't tell us (you gave "ERROR|0" as non-working input). even now, you give us *some code that gives me an output*, which can be virtually anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had two small errors in the first version of your code:

- `$result="ERROR...` (to assign, you have to use `result=value`)
- `<<< "$result` (you missed the second `"` to close quotation).

With this code, it works:

```
result="ERROR|0"  # From a complex sed exectution
IFS='|' read -a array <<< "$result"

if [ "${array[0]}" == "ERROR" ]; then
    echo "Error"
fi
```

#### In fact, I think you updated your code in the grace period and now it is fine.

I added `#!/bin/bash` in the first line and executed:

```
$ ./script
Error
```

Answer (score 0):

when you assign values to variables, do not use `$` notation.
e.g. use

```
 result="foo"
```

rather than

```
 $result="foo"
```

and then don't forget the terminating quotes when writing a string:

```
IFS='|' read -a array <<< "$result
```

misses the terminating quote in `"$result`.

a good syntax highlighter can help a lot (simply compare the syntax-highlighting in your question with that in the answers)

Comment: I've forgot the quotes and accidentally added the $ notation at begin because I had to adapt my script in order to make it clear. Nonetheless it still doesn't work